# Stripping value in PS and comparing if it is an integer value

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I am running PS cmdlet `get-customcmdlet` which is generating following output

```
Name                         FreeSpaceGB
----                         -----------
ABC-vol001                   1,474.201
```

I have another variable `$var=vol`
Now, I want to strip out just `001` and want to check if it is an integer.

I am using but getting null value

```
$vdetails = get-customcmdlet | split($var)[1]
$vnum = $vdetails -replace '.*?(\d+)$','$1'
```

My result should be integer `001`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumption: `get-customcmdlet` is returning a `pscustomobject` object with a property `Name` that is of type `string`.

```
$var = 'vol'
$null -ne ((get-customcmdlet).Name -split $var)[1] -as [int]
```

This expression will return `$true` or `$false` based on whether the cast is successful.

---

If your goal is to pad zeroes, you need to do that after-the-fact (in this case, I just captured the original string):

```
$var = 'vol'
$out = ((get-customcmdlet).Name -split $var)[1]
if ($null -ne $out -as [int])
{
    $out
}
else
{
    throw 'Failed to find appended numbers!'
}
```

Comment: I am getting `False` even though `001` in an integer value. I should get `True` as an output

Comment: @meallhour I was using the wrong method. Check my update